# Logarithm - Convert to exponential form

Tags: logarithms

this needs to be converted to exponential form and I can't seem to figure it out.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

$$10 \log(1+i) = \log 2$$

Answer (score 1):

Apply the basic logarithm property: $\log (1+i)^{10}=\log 2$, and $(1+i)^{10}=2$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that:

- $10\log(1+i)=\log((1+i)^{10})$

Therefore:

- $10\log(1+i)=\log2\implies$
- $\log((1+i)^{10})=\log2\implies$
- $(1+i)^{10}=2\implies$
- $1+i=\sqrt[10]{2}\implies$
- ${i}=\sqrt[10]{2}-1$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that 
$$ \log x=\log_e x=\ln x $$
We have
$$10 \log(1+i) = \log 2$$
$$ \log(1+i)^{10} = \log 2$$
$$ e^{\log(1+i)^{10}}= e^{\log 2}$$
$$ (1+i)^{10}= 2$$
$$ 1+i=\sqrt[10]{2} $$
$$ i=\sqrt[10]{2} -1$$
Where $i$ does **not** denote the imaginary unit and is just a poorly chosen variable name. If $i$ is intended to denote the imaginary unit, then this equation is false.